# Django difficulty using ModelAdmin.queryset with ModelAdmin.list_filter to limit the filter itrems displayed

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

In Django 1.5.1 I setup a SAAS system for internal use, where each department gets their own set of data.

To do that, I use **ModelAdmin.queryset** (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset) to limit all data to only the records that *belong* to the department of the currently logged in user.

This works perfect for the main Admin functions (summary tables etc.).  But anything I put on **"ModelAdmin.list_filter"** shows ALL values - obviously using the base query set and not the one I defined in **ModelAdmin.queryset**.

I can see how one can define a custom **ModelAdmin.list_filter** query here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter that lets you also define a custom filter manager, which can include a custom queryset.

But this is ***PER FILTER FIELD!***

That seems like an awful lot of work for something that should be automatic once you add **ModelAdmin.queryset**!

Is there a simpler way I'm missing here, or maybe this is something I should ticket?

Thanks in advance,

Rich.

***Peter, thanks for the kick in my pants.  Turns out my understanding of my own problem was wrong!***

================= Example from my code ================

```
class Company(models.Model):
    """Company model."""
    accountid = models.CharField(_('Account Number'), max_length=20, null=False, blank=True, help_text="Link to old system and records")
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200, unique=True, help_text=_("Enter full company name, no abbreviations. Duplicates are not allowed."))
    nickname = models.CharField(_('nickname'), max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_("Enter one or more keywords or abbreviations seperated by a space to make searching easier"))
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, populate_from=('name', ))
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, default="0", blank=False, null=False, editable=False, help_text="Indicate which site this record belongs to. ")


class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('type', 'lead_quality', )

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.message_user(request, "Warning: This is the ADMINISTRATOR view!!", 'warning')
            return qs
        return qs.filter(site__id=request.session['site'].id)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            if obj.site.id != request.session['site'].id:
                logger.debug("Contacts.Person.save_model: replacing site (%s) with (%s) " % (repr(obj.site), repr(request.session['site'])) )
        else:
            logger.debug("Contacts.Person.save_model: setting site (%s)" % (repr(request.session['site'])) )
        obj.site = request.session['site']
        obj.save()


class Person(models.Model):
    """Person model."""
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=200)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('slug'), max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, populate_from=('first_name', 'last_name'))
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_("If this person is associated with a Company, indicate which one here.") )
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, default="0", blank=False, null=False, editable=False, help_text="Indicate which site this record belongs to. ")


class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('company',)

    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PersonAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            self.message_user(request, "Warning: This is the ADMINISTRATOR view!!", 'warning')
            return qs
        return qs.filter(site__id=request.session['site'].id)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change:
            if obj.site.id != request.session['site'].id:
                logger.debug("Contacts.Person.save_model: replacing site (%s) with (%s) " % (repr(obj.site), repr(request.session['site'])) )
        else:
            logger.debug("Contacts.Person.save_model: setting site (%s)" % (repr(request.session['site'])) )
        obj.site = request.session['site']
        obj.save()

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name in ('company',):
            kwargs["queryset"] = Company.objects.get_query_set().filter(site__id=request.session['site'].id)
        return super(PersonAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

So when a User views the summary screen for **People**, and they click on the Filter for **Company**, they see choices belonging to other company divisions.

If they click on one belonging to another division they get an empty list since the PersonAdmin cannot actually access that record.

Comment: please show us some code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you expect the related fields in `list_filter` to care about the queryset on the admin class? Such filters do not generally remove values that don't have a related object present.

If you don't want that behavior, you can write a single filter class that limits the choices however you like as a subset of `django.contrib.admin.filter.RelatedFieldListFilter` and use that instead, either overriding its `choices` method (the queryset as you defined it on the model admin will be available as `cl.root_query_set` within that method) or overriding its `__init__` method to create `self.lookup_choices` differently - perhaps based on the request. I see no reason you should have to keep redefining the class - one definition should work with as many related fields as you like.

Here's a simple one that should only include items in the filter if the admin's filtered queryset has at least one object for the filter value:

```
class RelatedFieldRestrictedListFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):

    def choices(self, cl):
        from django.contrib.admin.views.main import EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE
        yield {
            'selected': self.lookup_val is None and not self.lookup_val_isnull,
            'query_string': cl.get_query_string({},
                [self.lookup_kwarg, self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
            'display': _('All'),
        }
        for pk_val, val in self.lookup_choices:
             if cl.root_query_set.filter(**{self.lookup_kwarg: pk_val}).exists():
                 yield {
                    'selected': self.lookup_val == smart_unicode(pk_val),
                    'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                        self.lookup_kwarg: pk_val,
                    }, [self.lookup_kwarg_isnull]),
                    'display': val,
                    }
        if (isinstance(self.field, models.related.RelatedObject)
                and self.field.field.null or hasattr(self.field, 'rel')
                    and self.field.null):
            yield {
                'selected': bool(self.lookup_val_isnull),
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                    self.lookup_kwarg_isnull: 'True',
                }, [self.lookup_kwarg]),
                'display': EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE,
            }
```

This does a separate query against the DB for each possible value in the `list_filter` field, so it's a bit inefficient - if that turns into a problem you should customize `__init__` instead.

Followup:
Ok, so the correct filter choices depend on the request session. That means you need to establish them in the `__init__` method of a subclass. Your example shows a related field, so I'll use `RelatedFieldListFilter` again - I'm honestly not sure the concept of a restricted queryset makes sense for any other kind of filter. To do that, the lazy method (shorter to write, less efficient) would be to call the superclass's `__init__`, then change `self.lookup_choices`. The less lazy method would be to entirely override `__init__`.

The lazy method is something like this:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class RelatedFieldRestrictedListFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):

    def __init__(self, field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path):
        super(RelatedFieldRestrictedListFilter, self).__init__(field, request, params, model, model_admin, field_path)
        if 'site' in request.session:
            self.lookup_choices = [(instance.pk, smart_unicode(instance) for instance in model.objects.filter(site=request.session['site'])]
        else:
            # something else here
```

The less lazy method would involve copying in the base code from the superclass's `__init__` method and replacing `self.lookup_choices = field.get_choices(include_blank=False)` line with the above.

Note that I'm allowing for the possibility that the session may not have a `site` - you should think about what you want to happen if that's the case. And maybe not bother changing `lookup_choices` if the user is a superuser.

Comment: Well, no, not "related fields" filter.  For the example I gave, "company" is a field in the database being summarized.  So it would be, for example, a list of customers for the current company division.  The problem is when a user in division "B" clicks on the Filter, they get a list that includes ALL companies from ALL divisions.  If they click on a company from division "A", they get a "record not found" error - since the change view uses the ModelAdmin.queryset.  Is that clearer?

Comment: So the fields aren't related to the state of the queryset but are themselves also limited based on the request? That's doable, but it leaves me even more confused about why you think that would be automatic. This would be easier to follow if you added your models and admin code to the question.

Comment: Actually, what you're describing ("they get a list that includes ALL companies from ALL divisions") isn't the normal behavior. Filters operate on the admin's queryset, so if you're limiting that queryset appropriately they won't show up in the change list whether or not they match the filters. It remains unclear to me whether you're worried about limiting the choices presented in the filters or the choices presented in the change list.

Comment: I can, but its a complex example.  Lets try using the simpler sample given for ModelAdmin.queryset. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset

`code`
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(author=request.user)
`code`

Comment: So if you actualy did this in your ModelAdmin, your interested in only letting a user see the records (s)he saved.  So, in any list view you would want all of the filter choices displayed to also belong to that user.  Otherwise, you would see choices that belong to other users.  And if you clicked on one in a filter, you would get an error - just as my users do.  Does this work?

Comment: And Thanks Peter for your reply.  I appreciate your help.  (I say this in advance in case I forget to say it later!)

Comment: OK, if you want to limit the choices in the filters you'll have to do that in a custom `__init__` method, since that gets the `request` instance. You say they're not related field filters - what kind of fields are they?

Comment: I appended to my original post.